# How to open a program in different Xephyr Displays?

Tags: linux, xorg, xterm, x-server, xephyr

I have two Xephyr displays created through PyVirtualDisplay, when I try to open `xterm` in both of them it works just fine, but many other programs will open twice on the same display.

So if I do this:

```
DISPLAY=":1001" gedit & DISPLAY=":1005" gedit &
```

it behaves differently than this:

```
DISPLAY=":1001" xterm & DISPLAY=":1005" xterm &
```

Why does it happen though?